# Firefox (only) Dynamic Form Action Not Working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iframe, file-upload

Console is returning blank for the action attr. I've moved the:

```
$('#file_upload').attr('action','io.cfm?action=updateitemfile&item_id='+$('.agenda-modal').attr('data-defaultitemid'));
```

Around in and out of the `.live('submit')` and no luck. I also tried it without the `+$('.agenda-modal').attr('data-defaultitemid')` part and it still returns blank. Ive removed everything in my form to JUST:

```
$('#file_upload').live('submit',function(event){
        $(this).attr('action','io.cfm?action=updateitemfile&item_id='+$('.agenda-modal').attr('data-defaultitemid'));
});
```

and still nothing. It submits to nowhere, and returns action=""

Lastly, it works in all other browsers, just not Firefox :( Does anyone have any ideas?

Here is the HTML just in case you want to see it:

```
<form id="file_upload" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" target="upload_target" action="">
    <input name="binary" id="file" size="27" type="file" /><br />
    <br><input type="submit" name="action" value="Upload" /><br />
    <iframe id="upload_target" name="upload_target" src="" style="display:none"</iframe>
</form>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on [this comment on the attr() documentation](http://api.jquery.com/attr/#comment-53374047), it appears that action must be capitalized to work in Firefox:

```
$('#file_upload').live('submit',function(event){
    $(this).attr('ACTION','io.cfm?action=updateitemfile&item_id='+$('.agenda-modal').attr('data-defaultitemid'));
});
```

I've got money that says that breaks it in IE...

Comment: nice find Pat! (why the hell wouldn't jQuery handle this natively?) anyways, ill try it out, let you know, and hopefully get you some points...

Comment: This information is incorrect in general.  It is not necessary to capitalize the "action" attribute *unless* an `<input>` in the form has a "name" attribute of "action".

Comment: Thanks for the info @Pointy.  I remember screwing up my form submits in IE once when I named an input as follows: `<input name="name"/>`.  Live and learn eh?

Comment: OMG, I had the same problem and capitalizing ACTION solved it. You are a king among men.

Comment: I see too many "thanks" but too few upvote! My +1 for you :-)